# How to Not alter font in webpage after opening a file (pdf or jpg) in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to not alter font in webpage after opening a pdf in ASP.NET C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499254/how-to-not-alter-font-in-webpage-after-opening-a-pdf-in-asp-net-c)

Previously I posted this question:

[How to open files from a specific route in ASP-NET c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498618/how-to-open-files-from-a-specific-route-in-asp-net-c)

in fact, I have already asked this however it was only a minor question so I guess it wasn't that important in the previous post, so I will ask here.

Whenever I open a pdf with:

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('FilePath');</script>");
```

All of the font in the page is altered, example, the letter's size increases and some of the letter's colors are switched to black instead of the font that I assigned.

Is there a way that I can work around that??

http://imageshack.us/a/img838/5145/beforeja.png

http://imageshack.us/a/img546/4760/afterw.png

Oh and I noticed that this also happens when you open images like jpg

Comment: Opening the same question again will not help to solve it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499254/how-to-not-alter-font-in-webpage-after-opening-a-pdf-in-asp-net-c

Comment: You *might* get better results if you try RegisterStartupScript instead of Response.Write like so: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myFileOpenScript", "<script>window.open('FilePath');</script>");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure writing directly with Response.Write is the best solution in this particular case.  My memory is vauge on this but it seems that I tried (a long time ago) writing directly to the output via Response.Write and ran into some odd behavior like you described.  The other SO members should be able to better elaborate why this happens but I *think* it has a bit to do with where you are in the page lifecycle and IIS Stream as to whether or not Response.Write will achive the desired behavior.  If you want to push files out directly to the client, you might consider MVC.  MVC makes it much easier to push a file out directly to the client by way of the FilePathResult Class.  You can mix and match MVC and WebForms if you like.  Scott Hansleman shows how to do this [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx).

If, however, you want to stick with WebForms, then here is a simple page I have thrown together to show how you can use RegisterStartupScript to open either of two local PDFs by clicking the respective button:

**ASPX:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Register Startup Script Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="bnOpenTest1PDF" runat="server" 
         OnClick="opnTest1PDF" Text="OpenPDF1" />
        <asp:Button ID="bnOpenTest2PDF" runat="server" 
         OnClick="opnTest2PDF" Text="OpenPDF2" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void opnTest1PDF(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
            this.GetType(),
            "myFileOpenScript",
            "<script>window.open('test1.pdf');</script>");
    }

    protected void opnTest2PDF(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
            this.GetType(),
            "myFileOpenScript",
            "<script>window.open('test2.pdf');</script>");
    }
}
```